# C++ Checking if a user input a valid answer

Tags: c++, string

I need to check if they input happy,sad or mad when prompted with:
input a mood (happy,sad,mad)
This is my code for it so far
count = 0;
    while (count<1){

```
    cout << ", How are you feeling today? (happy,sad,mad)" << endl;

    cin >> mood;

    if (mood == sad){

        cout << "im sorry you're feeling sad" << endl;

            count++;
    }

    else if (mood == happy) {

        cout << "I'm glad you're feeling happy!" << endl;

            count++;
    }

    else if (mood == mad){
        cout << "Don't be angry, there's so many happy things in life!" << endl;
    }
    else{

        cout << " invalid input " << endl;

        count = 0;
    }

    }
```

but if i put in happy,sad or mad it just goes to the invalid input. 
i also tried declaring string variables for them like 
    string happy=happy;
    string sad=sad;
    string mad=mad;

Comment: It looks like you are confusing variable names with text strings. They may be the same word, but they are unrelated. (Unless mad is a std::string with the value "mad", for example.)

Comment: How does this even compile? Post an MCVE.

Comment: Thou shalt use double quotes to signify a string. Do this and all shall be right in the world. Until the next bug.

Answer (score -4):

Two things:

1. Make sure you're initializing your String's correctly

   ```
   string happy = "happy";
   ```
2. Try using `string.compare()` rather than `==`

   ```
   mood.compare(happy);
   ```

For more details: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: The only thing wrong is `String` should be lowercase. Otherwise the code above is most certainly C++

Comment: `==` is fine... as I said, this is not Java.